# How to set a http session cookies in MongoDB functions?

Tags: mongodb, api, http, authentication, session-cookies

I have to connect to an API REST through MongoDB Realm Functions, using the GET method,  to collect data and store them in MongoDB Atlas.
The protocol is to make a first Http POST request to authenticate and receive session-cookies. But in MongoDB Realm Functions, I have to login first using context.http.post() before every context.http.get() request because MongoDB Realm Functions change session every time the function is fired.
The question is: How to use cookies session inside MongoDB Realm Functions with context.http.get()?
Someone has suggestions?
P.s.: I have already tried to store cookies and attach them in context.request.cookies, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Cookies are what you are looking for rather, look into authentication headers for the request.